# Why does 'find' command on Alpine seem to require escaping '?' but not on Ubuntu?

Tags: find, regular-expression, alpine-linux

Is this related to a bug, etc. or this is how it should be?

`find ./frontend -mindepth 1 -regex '^./dir1/dir2\(/.*\)?'` works on Ubuntu but not Alpine (docker)

`find ./frontend -mindepth 1 -regex '^./dir1/dir2\(/.*\)\?'` works on Alpine (docker) but not Ubuntu

Alpine: 3.14

Ubuntu: 18.04

Comment: One's probably GNU find and other busybox find

Comment: Alpine uses busybox as much as possible by default.  If you want GNU find, install `findutils`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They use [different syntaxes for regular expressions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y).

[GNU find's `-regex`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Full-Name-Patterns.html#index-_002dregex) uses [Emacs regular expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexps.html#Regexps) by default. This can be changed with the option [`-regextype`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Full-Name-Patterns.html#index-_002dregextype) which is specific to GNU find; other choices include POSIX BRE (basic regular expressions, as in grep and sed) and POSIX ERE (extended regular expressions, as in `grep -E` and (almost) awk).

[BusyBox find's `-regex`](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/findutils/find.c?h=1_34_0&id=d922947834160f356ebdee07af69e33cbe4b6057#n584) uses POSIX BRE (the default for the [`regexc` function](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/regexec.html)). Because BusyBox is designed to be small, there is no option to use a different regex syntax.

[FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=find&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+13.0-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html), macOS and [NetBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=find&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=NetBSD+9.2&arch=default&format=html) default to BRE, and can use ERE with the `-E` option.

[POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) does not standardize `-regex`.

For your command:

- In BRE (basic), grouping is `\(…\)`. The zero-or-one operator is `\?` if present, but it is an optional feature, present in BusyBox when built with Glibc (I'm not sure about other libc) but not on BSD. Zero-or-one can also be spelled `\{0,1\}`.
- In Emacs RE, grouping is `\(…\)` and the zero-or-one operator is `?`. Although Emacs itself also supports `\{0,1\}` to mean zero-or-one, GNU find's Emacs regex syntax doesn't.
- In ERE (extended), grouping is `(…)` and the zero-or-one operator is `?`.

If you need portability between the various implementations of `find` that implement `-regex`, you need to stick to POSIX BRE constructs (for the sake of BusyBox) that are spelled the same in GNU find's Emacs syntax. This means there's no zero-or-one operator.

```
find ./frontend -mindepth 1 \( -regex '^./dir1/dir2/.*' -o -regex '^./dir1/dir2' \)
```

Or, alternatively, arrange to pass `-regextype posix-basic` to GNU find.

```
case $(find --help 2>/dev/null) in
  *-regextype*) find_options='-regextype posix-basic';;
  *) find_options=;;
esac
find ./frontend $find_options -mindepth 1 -regex '^./dir1/dir2\(/.*\)\{0,1\}'
```

If `dir1` and `dir2` are plain strings an not regexes, you're not getting any use from `-regex` and you can just write

```
find ./frontend/dir1/dir2 -maxdepth 1
```

Comment: There’s also a fourth option that’s just as portable as the last one, but still works if you need the regex syntax and avoids the extra boilerplate of the second approach: Just use `find` to generate the base list of files, and then pipe that to `grep` to do the regex filtering. Not as efficient, but guaranteed to work on Busybox, GNU coreutils, and any POSIX compliant system. For example: `find ./frontend -maxdepth 1 | grep '^./dir1/dir2\(/.*\)\{0,1\}'`.