# Why does find -regex work different on different machines?

Tags: find, regular-expression, lubuntu, alpine-linux

So I got the following `find` command:

```
find ./test-folder -type d -mindepth 1 -regex "^.*/\d\{4\}-\d\{2\}-\d\{2\}$"
```

Previously I've created the folder `./testfolder` by `mkdir testfolder` and a folder in it `mkdir ./testfolder/2022-10-12`.

When running the `find` command with Bash in an alpine-based docker container everything works fine and it outputs `/path/to/testfolder/2022-10-12`

If I run the same command in bash on my Lubuntu machine it won't output anything.

I have not modified the find command or anything around it, I expected it to work on any machine, but the regex seems to behave differently. Matching `*` works, also matching an infinite number of digits `\d*` works, but as soon as I try to match `-` or use quantifiers as `{4}` it won't match anything anymore.

What could be the issue here? Moreover, how can I make it work on LUbuntu?

Comment: @AdminBee It technically does, but I am still not able to get any regex matching my required format working on Lubuntu. No matter what I try, nothing seems to work.

Not even `-regex "\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d"` works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a comment I deduce that the actual question is "How do I match the equivalent of `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}` on LUbuntu".

The problem is two-fold:

1. First, as explained e.g. in [Why does 'find' command on Alpine seem to require escaping '?' but not on Ubuntu?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/679615/why-does-find-command-on-alpine-seem-to-require-escaping-but-not-on-ubuntu), the default RegEx syntax on AlpineLinux and LUbuntu is different.
2. Second, the `\d`  character class is part of the ["PCRE" style extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) of the basic regular expressions, which is not supported on GNU `find` that comes with Lubuntu.

So, you should use the `-regextype` option to explicitly select a RegEx type with the features that you need, and then adhere to that style. In your case, you could use the [Extended Regular Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_extended):

```
find ./testfolder/ -mindepth 1 -regextype "egrep" -regex '^.*/[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}$'
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
So it seems there is no interoperable version of regex between busybox and gnu, should I use gnu find in my alpine containers then? Since I'm mostly developing on ubuntu this seems to be good thing to do. I don't think it's practicable to convert the format every time.

Comment: @Rudolf You're welcome. If you found the answer useful, you may consider [accepting it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) so that others facing a similar issue may find it more easily. As for your question, I don't have much experience with AlpineLinux, but it would seem that the `findutils` package of AlpineLinux provides GNU find, so the option may be supported there, too.